# Smoothly lerp a rigidbody

Tags: c#, input, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm wanting my player to move to the left when the player hits the left of the screen. Right now, my player only moves as and when I hold down my mouse button. What I'm really wanting is for him to continually move to the left until he hits the target position when I press the screen once.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing from my code to allow this to happen?

```
void FixedUpdate() 
{

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if(Input.mousePosition.x < (Screen.width*2)/3 && Input.mousePosition.y > Screen.height/3)
        {
            if(position == middle)
            {
                MoveLeft();
            }   
        }
    }
}

void MoveLeft()
{
    var pos = rigidbody.position;
    float xPosition = left.transform.position.x;
    pos.x = Mathf.Lerp(pos.x, xPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    rigidbody.position = pos;
}
```

My method is in the FixedUpdate because I'm moving the players rigidbody as oppose to translating the actual player.

Comment: I had to look this up, lerp = linear interpolation ;)

Comment: Yeah. It's meant to smoothly move one object between two points. There is a slerp which does the same but in a spherical movement, so good for orbits etc. But not what I can use here :(

Comment: For starters you should be using Time.fixedDeltaTime if you are calling the method from FixedUpdate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the player only moves when you hit mouse button because that's how your code is written: you check if the mouse is pressed every frame, and only if it is move the rigidbody.

If you want the player to move regardless of whether the mouse is still pressed or not, you should create some kind of variable to save the state of the player, and set to move left when the mouse button is pressed and set it to stop when the player reaches his target.

If I correctly understood your goal, it would look something like this:

```
bool moveLeft = false;

void FixedUpdate() 
{

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)
        && (Input.mousePosition.x < (Screen.width*2)/3 && Input.mousePosition.y > Screen.height/3))
    {
        moveLeft = true;
    }

    if (moveLeft
        && (position == middle))
    {
        MoveLeft();
    }
    else
    {
        moveLeft = false;
    }
}

void MoveLeft()
{
    var pos = rigidbody.position;
    float xPosition = left.transform.position.x;
    pos.x = Mathf.Lerp(pos.x, xPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    rigidbody.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that man good shout. What I'm wanting is for my player to only move when the user taps the left side of the screen (for now im using a mouse click) then for it move along on its merry way until it hits the end point. I implemented your check, but it still only moves a fraction when I click. I even modified my move left to use Time.fixedDeltatime as well.

Comment: Well, why does it stop? It should call MoveLeft() method every frame while moveLeft is true, what's setting it to false?

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Thank you for your help.